# Fuzzy string matching of domain names, is levenshtein best?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an email validator

Which at the moment does the following

- Validating correct format
- Checking the domain and testing for MX records.
- Validating the user and the mailserver by connecting to the mail server.

However i would like to be able to suggest a domain name correction if the user misspelled the domain name.

Forinstance the user typing user@gmali.com - this will result in an MX lookup failure, hence this is not a correct email.

In this situation i would like to match the entered domain against a list of domain names.

With which fuzzy string algorithm will i get the best results ?

Comment: Why do this? Wouldn't it be better just to let the user know the email address is incorrect? You're bound to guess wrong more often than is acceptable to users (for instance, Yahoo and Hotmail have loads of country specific domains that will make suggestions tricky).

Comment: "Forinstance the user typing user@gmali.com - this will result in an MX lookup failure" -- No, it will not. gmali.com has MX records, as will most other obvious misspellings of popular mail domains. (Edit: I just realised that by "MX lookup failure" you probably don't mean "failing to find the MX record". I expect you'll still get far too many bogus suggestions for this to be useful.)

Comment: We have alot of senior customers which do not know common domains, gmail.com, hotmail.com, yahoo.com or atleast when they look at an incorrect email they wont see the error and they will simply not correct these small spelling errors. Iam not trying to create suggestions for uncommon domains, iam merely trying to create a system that will suggest corrections if common domains are mispelled. My idea is to only make one suggestion the user.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best thing which should work for you is the algorithm [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)